# Sorting lists of polygon coordinates in counter-clockwise direction in Python

Tags: python

I have a number of sublists that contain coordinate tuples such that the tuples within a sublist form a polygon.

```
list_test = [[(0.115, 0.993), (0.319, 0.948), (0.236, 0.849)], [(0.319, 0.948), (0.640, 0.768), (0.236, 0.849), (0.471, 0.566)], [(0.115, -0.993), (-0.115, -0.993), (0.236, -0.849), (-0.236, -0.849), (0.0, -0.566)]]
```

These polygons are created by intersections of a rectangle and a line, so they can be a triangle, rectangle or pentagon (no "funny shapes" involved), and they all lie within the unit circle. How can I sort the coordinate tuples within each sublist in counter-clockwise direction?

Comment: 1) Compute the mean of x and y, which gives you the coordinates of the center. 2) Compute the angle from the center to each point, using math.atan() 3) Sort the points according to the angles.

Comment: @MartinWettstein thank you, that already helped me plenty!

Answer (score 1):

Just take the `atan` of each point based on origin and sort the values.

```
for points in list_test:
    points.sort(key=lambda x: math.atan2(x[1] - 0, x[0] - 0))
```

Simple plot for the given example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for points in list_test:
    for point in points:
        ax.scatter(point[0], point[1], c='b')
        ax.annotate(f" {point}", xy=point)
ax.axhline(y=0, color='k')
ax.axvline(x=0, color='k')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This showed a bit of weird behaviour for some of my polygons, but I managed to do it with the idea this answer gave me, thanks!